# Borrar datos de un JTable

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica, jtable

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo 2 JTable, el primer JTableEquipo se me carga todos los nombre de los equipos que tengo y según haga clic sobre algún de esos equipo, se me abre otro JTableDatosJugador con todos los datos del jugador. En el JTableDatosjugador tengo un botón para dar de baja a dicho jugador y se me borra el jugador pero si vuelvo a abrir el JTableDatosJugador el jugador que he borrado antes aparece otra vez. 
He intentado borrar los datos de las 2 tablas pero sigue pasando lo mismo.

**Método para borrar los datos del jugador del JTableDatosJugador**

```
    int[] rows = tablaVNT.getSelectedRows();
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        modeloVTN.removeRow(rows[i] - i);  
    }
```

**también he utilizado ese otro código pero me pasa lo mismo**

```
    int fila = tablaVNT.getSelectedRow();

    if(fila == 0){
        modeloVTN.removeRow(fila);          
    }
```

**¡¡Gracias!!**

Comment: Es probable que estés abriendo la tabla con el modelo viejo. Puedes mostrar el código donde vuelves a abril la tabla y donde le pones el modelo.

Answer (score 0):

> Codigo del JTableVerEquipos
> **Con ese método relleno el JTableVerEquipos e introduzco los equipos en la tabla cuando no se repiten**

```
public void rellenarTabla() {
    String[] equipos = new String[10];
    int cont = 0;

    for (Jugador jugador : gestor.getEquipo()) {
        boolean repetido = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < equipos.length; i++) {
            if (jugador.getN_equipo().equals(equipos[i])) {
                repetido = true;
            }
        }
        if (repetido == false) {
            equipos[cont] = jugador.getN_equipo();
            cont++;
        }
    }
    modelo.addColumn("Equipos", equipos);
}
```

**Según haga clic sobre algún equipo de la tabla, se me abre la nueva ventana con los todos los datos de los jugadores**

```
public void clicEquipo() {

    int filaSeleccionada = tabla.getSelectedRow();
    VentanaNuevaTabla vtn = new VentanaNuevaTabla(prin, gestor);

    switch (filaSeleccionada) {
        case 0:
            for (Jugador jugador : gestor.getEquipo()) {

                if (jugador.getN_equipo().equals("Real Madrid")) {
                    vtn.modeloVTN.addRow(jugador.toArray());
                   
                }
            }
            vtn.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
            break;
        case 1:
            for (Jugador jugador : gestor.getEquipo()) {
                if (jugador.getN_equipo().equals("Barcelona")) {
                    vtn.modeloVTN.addRow(jugador.toArray());
                }
            }
            vtn.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();   
         break;}
```

**Este es el código de borrar el jugador seleccionado del JTableDatosJugador**

```
    TreeSet<Jugador> equipo = gestor.getEquipo();
    Iterator<Jugador> iter = equipo.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        if (tablaVNT.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
            modeloVTN.removeRow(tablaVNT.getSelectedRow());
            break;
        }
    }
```

Espero que el código te pueda ayudar, **¡gracias por la ayuda!**